# Coherence - High CPU consumption

Tags: oracle-coherence

I am using coherence in my application, One of my thread is consuming High CPU.
Please find below thread dump of thread which is consuming high CPU.

```
"PacketReceiver" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002b5608179000 nid=0x2476 runnable [0x00002b57d6377000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Native Method)
    - locked <0x00002b57b13e1d70> (a java.io.EOFException)
    at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:181)
    at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:29)
    at java.io.IOException.<init>(IOException.java:30)
    at java.io.EOFException.<init>(EOFException.java:32)
    at com.tangosol.io.nio.ByteBufferReadBuffer$ByteBufferInput.readInt(ByteBufferReadBuffer.java:496)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.Packet.isForMember(Packet.CDB:7)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.Packet.extract(Packet.CDB:21)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.packetProcessor.PacketReceiver.onNotify(PacketReceiver.CDB:27)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:51)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing similar kind of cpu issue in oracle coherence proxy.noded are idle and i can see many Transport service RUNNABLE Threads in thread dump. These Runnable thread are causing high cpu usage.

All RUNNABLE Threads are comming from cohernce.jar

Comment: what insight does this add on top of what's in the question post already?